# Multiple Entity Framework contexts out of sync?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependency-injection, entity-framework-6, autofac

We have an ASP.NET MVC 5, EF6, AutoFac application.

All dependency injection happens via Autofac. We inject `IUnitOfWork` and `DbContext` on a `.InstancePerRequest()` lifetime scope.

At one point we register a user in an AccountController and add extra information in a separate service and then come back to the AccountController to redirect the user back to the home/index.

```
return Redirect("/#/intake/" + dbUser.IntakeIds.First(x => x.IsLoggedInUser).Id);
```

Once the redirect succeeds, we retrieve the user again and display it.

However, the extra information is not there.

If we go into debug mode, and go slowly, step by step, then everything works.
If I add a `Thread.Sleep(1000)` after the call to the service, then everything works.

This leads me to believe that the redirect to /home/index creates a new request, and thus a new context. The old context might not have had time to fully complete the transaction?

Comment: If I understand right, you insert or update data in this seperate service ? But after redirect you don't get this data. Is your service doing async works ?

Comment: I would do logging on instantiation and operations inside the request to see if instances of the context are the same. I suspect that your `Redirect` might be a problem.

Comment: Looks like a timing / synchronization problem, not a EF/Autofac problem.
Proof, I guess, is that your code works simply with a `Thread.Sleep(1000)` and without changing any other configuration.